# How to implement a RecyclerView when using Model View Presenter pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp

I am working with MVP for the first time and I believe I get the idea of it but I am not sure about the RecyclerView. As far as I can say, MVP is about making views as passive as possible so all business logic goes to the Presenter but how can this be achieved for the Recycler View?

Here is my code so far:

**Contract**

```
public interface PhotosContract {
// View
interface View {//: IBaseActivity {
    fun showPhotos(photos: ArrayList<Photo>)
    fun showText(message: String)
}
// Presenter
interface Presenter {//: IBasePresenter<View> {
    fun getPhotos()
}
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class PhotosPresenter(var view: PhotosContract.View) :PhotosContract.Presenter {

var dataList = ArrayList<Photo>()

override fun getPhotos() {
    //call for endpoint
    val call : Call<ArrayList<Photo>> = ApiClient.getClient.getPhotos()

    call.enqueue(object: Callback<ArrayList<Photo>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Photo>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("FAIL","FAILED")
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ArrayList<Photo>>,
            response: Response<ArrayList<Photo>>
        )
        {
            Log.d("SUCCESS","SUCCESSED")

            dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)
            Log.d("SIZELIST",dataList.size.toString())

            view.showPhotos(dataList)
            view.showText("SUCCESS")
        }

    })

}

}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
class PhotosAdapter(private var dataList: List<Photo>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.PhotosViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotosAdapter.PhotosViewHolder {
    return PhotosViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_home, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotosAdapter.PhotosViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val dataModel = dataList[position]
    holder.titleTextView.text = dataModel.title
}

class PhotosViewHolder(itemLayoutView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView){
    var titleTextView: TextView = itemLayoutView.tv_title
}

}
```

**Activity**

```
class PhotosActivity : AppCompatActivity(),PhotosContract.View {
private lateinit var presenter: PhotosPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos)

    presenter = PhotosPresenter(this)

    presenter.getPhotos()

}

override fun showPhotos(photos: ArrayList<Photo>) {
    photosRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    photosRecyclerView.adapter = PhotosAdapter(photos,this)

    photosRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun showText(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it when I used MVP. In your contract, define an additional view named `ItemView`. The way I do it, each item view holder is a MVP view. The view is dumb, so it just calls the presenter whenever something happens, and the presenter calls it back.

```kotlin
interface MyContract {

    interface View {
        fun setTitle(title: String)
    }

    // Add this interface here
    interface ItemView {
        fun bindItem(item: Item)
    }

    interface Presenter {
        fun attach(view: View)
        fun detach()

        val itemCount: Int
        fun onItemClicked(pos: Int)
        fun onBindItemView(itemView: ItemView, pos: Int)
    }
}
```

The adapter is also dumb. When it needs to bind an item view holder, it calls the presenter to do it.

```kotlin
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    // How many items do we have? We don't know, ask the presenter.
    override fun getItemCount() = presenter?.itemCount ?: 0

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // How to bind the item if we only have position? We don't know, ask the presenter.
        presenter?.onBindItemView(holder, position)
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `ViewHolder` implements the `MyContract.ItemView` interface. Again, it's just a view so it has no responsibility by itself. It just delegates to the presenter.

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), MyContract.ItemView {

    private val txv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view)

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener {
            // What to do here, we only have the item's position? Call the presenter.
            presenter?.onItemClicked(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    override fun bindItem(item: Item) {
        txv.text = item.text
    }
}
```

And finally the presenter:

```kotlin
class MyPresenter : MyContract.Presenter {

    private var view: View? = null

    private val items = mutableListOf<Item>()

    override fun attach(view: View) {
        this.view = view
        // ...
    }

    override fun detach() {
        view = null
    }

    override val itemCount: Int
        get() = items.size

    override fun onItemClicked(pos: Int) {
        val item = items[pos]
        // ...
    }

    override fun onBindItemView(itemView: ItemView, pos: Int) {
        itemView.bindItem(items[pos])
    }

    // ...
}
```

The view for completeness, but nothing new here:

```
class MyView : Fragment(), MyContract.View {

    private var presenter: Presenter? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View) {
        // Attach presenter
        presenter = MyPresenter()
        presenter?.attach(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        // Detach the presenter
        presenter?.detach()
        presenter = null
    }

    // ...
}
```

That's just one way to do it, I'm sure there are a lot of others. I just like this one because all the responsibility belongs to the presenter, there's no business logic anywhere else.

Eventually, you'll want to make changes to your list and notify the adapter. For this, add a couple methods in your `View` contract like `notifyItemInserted(pos: Int)` and call them when needed from the presenter. Or, better yet, use `DiffUtil` so you don't have to manage it yourself!

Once you have a good understanding of MVP though, I strongly suggest you move to MVVM as it is the official architecture promoted by Google. Most people also find it a lot more convenient than MVP.

If you have any questions don't hesitate.

Comment: I have problems with implementing your suggestion. 
First, when  I try to implement Contract.Presenter in the Presenter class it shows me an error that the Presenter has a parameter which I see in the Contact (<V:View>) 
Also, how do I call the presenter in the recyclerView Adapter?

Comment: Oops I forgot to remove the generic parameter, it was from one of my projects. I changed it. For calling the presenter from the adapter you can either pass the presenter in the adapter's constructor or make the adapter an inner class to the view.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Now it works. The last thing I want to ask is how do you do an intent here to another activity. I saw another stackoverflow question but seems like people can't agree on one solution. @Nicolas

Comment: Add a method to the view contract like `openActivity()` and call it from the presenter.